# Restrict Specific Variable In Bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have a script that sets various variables.

```
maxMemSize=8g
poolThreadCount=4
...
```

I have to execute this script on multiple system, all of them running CentOS. Now what is required is to restrict setting of some of these variable on some of the systems. For example on system1, `maxMemSize` should not be set, while on system2 setting `poolThreadCount` should be restricted.

Like the way we can set `readonly` environmental variables to restrict `export` for those specific variables, can we do some similar trick to restrict setting specific variables in bash scripts too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict variable re-definition you can set it as read only in your `~/.bashrc` or in any other file, lets say `~/.readonly`:

```
readonly maxMemSize=3g
readonly poolThreadCount=2
```

Now you need to tell your bash which init file should run before it start execution. This is defined by a environmental variable `$BASH_ENV`:

```
export BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc
```

or

```
export BASH_ENV=~/.readonly
```

Now execute your script under `bash`

```
bash initThreadRead.sh
```

Comment: Huh?  How does this enforce the requirement that the variable should *not* be set on some systems?  Or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @tripleee set `maxMemSize` on system1 and `poolThreadCount` on system2. This will cause script, on system1, to set `poolThreadCount` but not `maxMemSize` and vice versa.